# Causality test for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, causality

For time series there is the Granger causality test. Is there some causality test for the logistic regression?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is your logistic model time-dependent?

Comment: My logistic model is not time-dependent. And my question more specifically asks whether it is possible to test, once the model is fit, whether the independent variables cause the dependent variable and not the other way around.

Answer (score 7):

Estimating causal relationships is hard.  You can't expect to be given an easy test that can be applied the same way regardless of your data and works reliably.  The Granger causality test can't offer you that for time series, even if some people sell it that way.

Well designed randomized controlled trials are very helpful.  In their absence, you better have substantive knowledge to guide your modelling.  If you want to understand causal inference, I recommend starting with a book like [Morgan and Winship's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521671930).  Though I'm sure there is good material on this site and elsewhere online.

Comment: Excellent answer. Granger causality is not causality. Christmas cards Granger-cause Christmas, but they certainly do not cause it in the philosophical/dictionary sense of the word.

Comment: That book looks good; I had not seen it and have ordered it.